# Setting A variable with the first word from another variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, cpu-word

I need to pull the first word from a variable in my batch script to another variable.

ex

if %hello% had "apples are awesome" in it and was pulled and put into %hi%

%hi% would say "apples"

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "hi="    
for %%h in (%hello%) do if not defined hi set "hi=%%h"
echo %hi%
```

should work, as would

```
set "hi="    
for %%h in (%hello%) do set "hi=%%h"&goto done
:done
echo %hi%
```

Note that the `set "var=string"` syntax ensures that trailing spaces on the line, as left by some editors, are not included in the value assigned.

You don't say clearly whether the value of `hello` is `apples are awesome`or `"apples are awesome"` - the first is a string of three words with space-separators, the second a single string containing one "word" which contains spaces. I've assumed the former.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a `for` loop:

```
for /f %%h in ("%hello%") do [command that uses %%h]
```

The behaviour of "for" in this circumstance is to split its input up into lines (there is only one, assuming there are no newline characters in your input variable), then split each line into tokens on spaces (you can change the delimiter using the `"delim=[chars]"` option) and pass the first token of each line to the specified command (you can use `"tokens=n,n,..."` to get at tokens other than the first on the line).

Note that AIUI you can only use a single letter variable name for the variable to receive the word, so you can't use `%%hi` as you requested.

(This is all untested, as I'm not at a machine running Windows at the moment, but ought to work if I'm reading the documentation correctly.)

Comment: Just clarifying that above you could use `set "hi=%%h"` after the `do` keyword.